# How to debug query regarding $_FILES especially file inputs?

Tags: php, mysql

I had this query using php in inserting images after submitting the form It says "Requirements submitted succesfully" but there is no data inserted in database.

This is my code so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['sumit'])){
    $count = count($_FILES);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dummyclients_tbl WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
    if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $sid = $row['user_id'];
        $coll =$row['college'];
        $stat = "Pending";

        $query = "INSERT INTO request_tbl (user_id,document_id,imgreq1,imgreq2,imgreq3,imgreq4,imgreq5,imgreq6,imgreq7,request_status,college) VALUES ('$sid','$passed_id'";
        for($i = 1; $i <= $count; ++$i){
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgreq'.$i]['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['imgreq'.$i]['size']){
                $query .= ",'" . base64_encode(file_get_contents(addslashes($_FILES['imgreq'.$i]['tmp_name']))) . "'";
            }else{
                $query .= ",NULL";
            }
        }
        $query .= ",'$stat','$coll')";
        ?>
            <script>alert('Requirements Successfully Submitted!');</script>
        <?php
       // saveimage($query);
    }
    else{

        ?>
            <script>alert('Error while submitting form!');</script>
        <?php

    }
}
```

I dont know where did I go wrong so please if anyone can help I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Nowhere do you actually *run* your query.  You need to execute `$query` (right before your "Requirements Successfully Submitted" alert)

Comment: Also, see the thousands of posts that tell you NOT to use `mysql_`, instead use PDO or mysqli_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Thanks @cale_b I am well aware of that but we are required to use mysql for the mean time while learning.

Comment: Your code failed; use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and `$query = "INSERT INTO request_tbl` was never queried with `mysql_query()`. You're using the same variable for both queries here, being `$query`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after:

```
$query .= ",'$stat','$coll')";
```

add

```
mysql_query($query)
```

Comment: It still throws the message "Requirements successfully submitted" but still no data is inserted in the database.

Comment: quite possible parameters number now is not valid.
before mysql_query($query) add "echo $query" and try to submit it into phpmyadmin - you will find error than.

ouch, and mysql_ is quite old and you should move to mysqli_...

Comment: It is now working fine. I just forgot to set the variables to accept `NULL` values. Anyways thanks @ Small Web Dev you helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So it is true that I did not execute the query and forgot to put `mysql_query($query);` after `$query .= ",'$stat','$coll')";` . And that lead me to solving another problem wherein I did not set the fields in the database to receive `NULL` values which is the cause of the error.